# Google places autocomplete not providing suggestion for some valid strings

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I'am working on latest **google places autocomplete** api. I'am not getting any suggestion when i pass some valid string to the **FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest** like *cubbon park, lal bagh*. Here is my code

```
FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest predictionsRequest = FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.builder()
    .setCountry("in")
    .setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.ADDRESS)
    .setSessionToken(token)
    .setQuery(charSequence.toString())
    .build();

placesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(predictionsRequest).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<FindAutocompletePredictionsResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<FindAutocompletePredictionsResponse> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    FindAutocompletePredictionsResponse predictionsResponse = task.getResult();
                    if (predictionsResponse != null) {
                            predictionList = predictionsResponse.getAutocompletePredictions();

                            for (int i = 0; i < predictionList.size(); i++) {
                                  Log.d("prediction", predictionList.get(i).getFullText(null).toString());
                            }

                     }
            } else {
                  Log.d("prediction", "prediction fetching task unsuccessful");
            }
        } });
```

When i pass cubbon park or lal bagh as the string i recieve **prediction fetching task unsuccessful** message in my logs.

Comment: Using your code, when I query "cubbon park", I get "Cubbon Park Road, Nunegundlapalli, Ambedkar Veedhi, Bengaluru, Karnataka, India" as output. So this looks like it's an issue with your app or project setup. What error do you get if you log the actual ApiException?